# C++, fastest method of getting angle into a specified range?

Tags: c++

what's the fastest way of getting a variable into a given range? For example, make sure that an angle "double alpha" is always within (0.0, 2*Pi).

I found two solutions myself, one of them is much slower and the other looks way to complicated for such an easy task. There must be a better way, or not?

```
//short, but very slow (so it's a no-go);
return asin(sin(alpha));

//much faster, but seems ugly (two while loops to change a variable? come on!)
while (alpha < 0.0)
{
    alpha += 2.0 * M_PI;
}
while (alpha >= 2.0 * M_PI)
{
    alpha -= 2.0 * M_PI;
}
return alpha;
```

Comment: Be careful, you quickly lose accuracy if the angle is large.  fmod() doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of implementing this by hand, I suggest you use the `fmod()` family of functions: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmodf which does exactly this. You'll still need to take care of negative results yourself, though:

```
alpha = fmod(alpha, 2.0 * M_PI);
if (alpha < 0.0)
    alpha += 2.0 * M_PI;
return alpha;
```

Comment: Handle negative results by first adding 360.0 before fmod(). Usually fixes any auto-generated results, but not a user-input one.

Comment: @drysdam Usually calculations are done in radians, not in degrees. Also, `alpha` might be less than -2π, in which case adding 2π (i.e. a full circle) will not do it.

Comment: Well yes, that's why I said "auto-generated results". Meaning the output of a function is usually going to be from -360 (or -2π, whatever) to +360 (or 2π). Just add 360 to it and then fmod to get a "simplest possible representation".